# ¿Como puedo autocompletar un @Html.DropDownListFor?

Tags: c#, mvc

Estoy trabajando con MVC y tengo este código:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdDiag2,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CIE10, " ", new { onchange = "", @class = "form-control", style = "width:410px;"})
```

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de hacer que el *dropdown* se autocomplete según lo que el usuario digite, para que no sea tan difícil para el usuario buscar tantos registros de la base de datos.

Comment: Para eso lo mejor es usar algúna libreria para el front que ya exista, yo uso [Select2](https://select2.org/) y me funciona muy bien.

Comment: Un buscador inteligente?

Comment: Me temo que vas a tener que tirar de un helper tipo Kendo o de Ajax con jQuery.

Comment: Puedes agregar un ejemplo de funcionamiento, porque dices que asi mejorars el funcionamiento de busqueda en BAse de datos

Answer (score 2):

Tendrias que hacer tu propio componente o utilizar una libreria que ya lo haga(que es mas recomendable).

Si decides utilizar una libreria, utiliza [select2](https://select2.org/configuration):

```js
$("select").select2();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select style="width:400px">
  <option>Azul</option>
  <option>Rojo</option>
  <option>Verde</option>
  <option>Amarillo</option>
</select>
```

En tu caso solo tendrias que agregarle un id al DropDown y aplicarle el plugin:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdDiag2,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CIE10, " ", new { onchange = "", @class = "form-control", style = "width:410px;", id = "mi-lista" })

<script>
 $("#mi-lista").select2();
</script>
```

Esta libreria requiere de [jquery](https://jquery.com/) para funcionar.

Comment: Muchas gracias!, me sirvio bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Para autocompletar un combo no alcanza con usar los `helpers` de `asp.net mvc`, deberas usar `javascript` o mejor `jquery`

Si a esto lo unes con una llamada `ajax` podrias invocar un action del controler para obtener un `json` que liste segun se vaya escribiendo

[jQuery AutoComplete from Database in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-AutoComplete-from-Database-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

veras que se crea un controles que retorna un json

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix)
{
    NorthwindEntities entities = new NorthwindEntities();
    var customers = (from customer in entities.Customers
                     where customer.ContactName.StartsWith(prefix)
                     select new
                     {
                       label = customer.ContactName,
                       val = customer.CustomerID
                     }).ToList();

    return Json(customers);
}
```

el cual lo invoca desde jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#txtCustomer").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/AutoComplete/',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return item;
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("#hfCustomer").val(i.item.val);
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

la idea es que el json de respuesta se asigne el control para listarlo

Esa misma tecnica es la que deberia aplicar en tu implementacion, pero como veras no alcanza con asp.net mvc solo